# In the job tab, no histogram appears

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, experimental-realization

(Newbie here) Accessing IBM Q Experience on a Windows 7 operating system and using the Google Chorme browser. I can completely assemble my circuit, using the IBM Quantum Composer and when executing it goes to the area job, I hope to finish the whole process, but when I press to see the results, only what appears in the image appears, I can't go down the page for the histogram presentation, however when accessing the same Job tab via my cell phone, the histogram and the circuit that was shown appear.

[Screenshot from IBM Q Experience]
[image]

Comment: Do your circuits have measurements? There won't be any results to plot if there are no measurements.

Comment: @jyu00 Can you submit a circuit to the hardware without measurement?

Comment: I believe I already saw this error with another user, his antivirus was blocking this somehow and by disabling it and configuring it another way it worked, maybe you could try that?

Comment: @KAJ226 Yes you can submit a circuit without measurement. I don't remember why people would want to do that though.

Comment: @jyu00 interesting. Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @jyu00 Yes, circuits have measurements. I can see the histograms on the site if I log in via my cell phone, but on the PC I can't see these histograms...

Comment: @Lena Thank you, this solution worked, both the histograms and the circuit came back to me in the job tab

Comment: @IkkyR great! You’re welcome, happy to hear that! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange.

This offers a way for you to retrieve your histogram but not exactly the solution to your problem. So hopefully it will be useful somehow.

First, note that each job you submitted has a `job_ID`. You actually can see it on the top left of your screenshot. You can "copy and paste" this JobID into line 6 of the script below

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
%matplotlib inline
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')
job = backend.retrieve_job('ENTER JOB_ID HERE')
counts = job.result().get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts, color='black', title="Result")
```

Executing this script through the Jupyter Notebook provided in Quantum Lab will print out your Histogram. For instance, using a JobID for one of my old job, I printed out the following.

[image]

Again, not the exact solution to your question but at least this should provide you a way to retrieve your result, plot it, and not wasting your time having to rerun your experiment to get a new plot.