# I can't see the results of my of my jobs

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience

New user here. I tried to run a test circuit which I submitted to ibmq_santiago to run, but now I cannot see my results. No histogram, no circuit, only the status timeline. I believe the problem is that my antivirus recognizes this URL as blacklisted and cancels the connection, because that's the message I get every time I try to view my results, but I don't get why it would do that. Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Hello, I assume you have the same problem as here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16676/in-the-job-tab-no-histogram-appears?noredirect=1#comment24567_16676 ? A workaround is explained on the only answer in order to see the results. Indeed, it is highly possible it is because of your antivirus (as I stated in the comments of the question I linked), maybe if you try and reconfigure it it will work better?

Answer (score 1):

As @Lena mentioned in the comment, you can use the alternative route that I proposed in [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16677/9858). But since it seems you also wanted to extract the circuit(s), you can add the following line: (Note that you can have more than 1 circuit in your job, hence more than 1 histogram plot)

```
for circuit in job.circuits():
    print(circuit)
```

So the complete script would be:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
%matplotlib inline
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')
job = backend.retrieve_job('ENTER JOB_ID HERE')
for circuit in job.circuits(): #viewing all the circuit in your job submission. 
    print(circuit)

counts = [job.result().get_counts()[i] for i in range(4) ] 
plot_histogram(counts[0], color='black', title="Result") #pick the histogram correspond to the circuit that you want to view
```